# Display data from text file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I need to display/append the data from a file, *file.txt*, containing 400 lines which are in the following format:

```
http://www.exemple.com/img1.jpg, title1, subtitle1, description1;
http://www.exemple.com/img2.jpg, title2, subtitle2, description2;
http://www.exemple.com/img3.jpg, title3, subtitle3, description3;
http://www.exemple.com/img4.jpg, title4, subtitle4, description4;
http://www.exemple.com/img5.jpg, title5, subtitle5, description5;
```

I know how to append 1 line into a `<div>`. But, here we have 4 elements on each line. I need to turn them into 4 elements that I could use to display them.

I am using this jQuery snippet that works fine for each line with 1 element and splits at the end of the line.

```
$.get('file.txt', function(data) {
  //var fileDom = $(data);

  var lines = data.split("\n");

  $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
    $('#display').append('<div><img src="' + elem + '"/></div>');
  });
});
```

The HTML output would be:

```
$('#display').append('<div class="container"><div class="left"><img src="' + src + '"/></div><div class="right">' + title + '<br/>' + subtitle + '<br/>' + description + '</div></div>');
```

Thanks for insights!

Comment: What output do you want? URL, Title, Subtitle, Description all on own lines?

Comment: You have a comma separated string. You have already used [`spilt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) once. Why are you not just using `elem.split(',')` again to split the string into the potions you want?

Comment: @Summer Evans Yes, the ouput would be the 4 elements for each line and stop at the ";" then do it again and this 400 times.

Comment: Looks like you already got some answers. Another time, please provide an example of the resulting HTML which you desire to end up with. For example:`<div><img src="http://www.exemple.com/img1.jpg"/>title1<br/>subtitle1<br/>description1</div>`  Would be one possible HTML result from the first line. As it is we have to **guess** as to what is that you desire.

Comment: @Summer Evans  Sorry, you are right... This exactly the HTML output I wanted.

Comment: @Makyen very good answer from you, it works :)  thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could `split` a second time:

```
$.each(lines, function(n, line) {
    // Breaks up each line into ['src', 'title', 'subtitle', 'description']
    var elements = line.split(', ');
    $('#display').append('<div><img src="' + elements[0] + '"/></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split on the `' '`:

```
$.get('file.txt', function(data) {
    //var fileDom = $(data);

    var lines = data.split("\n");

    $.each(lines, function(line, elem) {
        var parts = line.split(', '), // this splits the line into pieces
            src = parts[0],
            title = parts[1],
            subtitle = parts[2],
            description = parts[3].slice(0, -1); // remove the ';' from the description

        // at this point, you have the pieces of your line and can do whatever
        // you want with the data

        $('#display').append('<div><img src="' + src + '"/></div>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error resides on the way you split...

You need to do something like that, (`.when(file)` should be replaced with `.get('file.txt')`:

```js
var file = "http://www.exemple.com/img1.jpg, title1, subtitle1, description1; http://www.exemple.com/img2.jpg, title2, subtitle2, description2; http://www.exemple.com/img3.jpg, title3, subtitle3, description3; http://www.exemple.com/img4.jpg, title4, subtitle4, description4; http://www.exemple.com/img5.jpg, title5, subtitle5, description5;";

function AppendImagesCtrl($) {
  $
//  .get('file.txt')
  .when(file) // this is a fake
  .then(file => file.split(/; ?\n? ?/))
  .then(lines => lines.map((line, i) => {
    line = line.trim();
    if(!line) { return ""; }
    
    let [
      img, title, subtitle, description
    ] = line.split(/, ?n? ?/);
    
    return `<article id="${(i + 1)}">
<h1>${title}</h1>
<img src="${img}" alt="${img}" />
</article>`;
  }))
  .then(view => $('#example').append(view))
  ;  
}

window.jQuery(document).ready(AppendImagesCtrl);
```

```css
img { width: 100px; height: 50px; background: cyan; }
article { padding: 5px 10px; background: lightseagreen; margin-bottom: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```