# Generate HTML in JQuery using Append()

Tags: jquery, append, anchor

Is there a way for JQuery to actually generate the HTML in the page source? I am trying to add anchor tags for each row but they do not link since the snippet does not generate the HTML. Thanks!

[> Link to previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799914/display-data-from-text-file-with-jquery)

```
   $.get('file.txt', function(data) {
    var i = 0;   
    var lines = data.split("\n");
    $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
    var elements = elem.split(','); 

    $('#display').append('<div><img src="' + elements[0] + '"/></div>');

            });
        });
```

Comment: provide an example of what `file.txt` contains...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the ***jQuery*** way is the following:

```
$('<div/>', {
  'html': $('<img/>', {
    'src': 'http://placehold.it/100x100'
  }),
  'class': 'some-class-name',
  'data-attr': 'custom data attribute'
}).appendTo('#display');
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6jqds8gx/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

See [jQuery() API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2)

See [Creating DOM Elements](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

```
var newdiv = $("<div>"); //create a new div element and select it.
newdiv.appendTo("body"); //append the new div to body.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error resides on the way you split...

You need to do something like that, (`.when(file)` should be replaced with `.get('file.txt')`:

```js
var file = "http://www.exemple.com/img1.jpg, title1, subtitle1, description1; http://www.exemple.com/img2.jpg, title2, subtitle2, description2; http://www.exemple.com/img3.jpg, title3, subtitle3, description3; http://www.exemple.com/img4.jpg, title4, subtitle4, description4; http://www.exemple.com/img5.jpg, title5, subtitle5, description5;";

function AppendImagesCtrl($) {
  $
//  .get('file.txt')
  .when(file) // this is a fake
  .then(file => file.split(/; ?\n? ?/))
  .then(lines => lines.map((line, i) => {
    line = line.trim();
    if(!line) { return ""; }
    
    let [
      img, title, subtitle, description
    ] = line.split(/, ?n? ?/);
    
    return `<article id="${(i + 1)}">
<h1>${title}</h1>
<img src="${img}" alt="${img}" />
</article>`;
  }))
  .then(view => $('#example').append(view))
  ;  
}

window.jQuery(document).ready(AppendImagesCtrl);
```

```css
img { width: 100px; height: 50px; background: cyan; }
article { padding: 5px 10px; background: lightseagreen; margin-bottom: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"></div>
```